# Change source on word from excel links

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

I am exploring ways to link word with data from excel so that I can avoid manually copying excel data to word and making manual mistakes. Currently, I am trying to paste data from Excel as an HTML link and it works well, with the exception that it seems to create multiple source from same excel.

[image]

I wonder are there ways to unify the sources or otherwise allow the source to be updated all at once?

Comment: From your image, you linked 3 different cells from Excel to Word, and they are not a table, so the source is different. In my opinion, the sources are unable to be unified under your case.

Comment: @Emily Thanks for the comment, As you may see the source is the same excel file (Book1). It would be quite disappointing if the links aren't updateable fastly, thanks anyway

Comment: Are you against embedding Excel file within Word? Example: within Word Insert tab, Object (under Text section), choose 'Microsoft Excel Worksheet' or Create from File tab if you're wanting an existing file embedded; do not check 'Display as icon'

Comment: @gregg As long as I have a good way of 1. Linking the embedded excel file to other excel files and 2. Remove the embed file in the final report while keeping the content and 3 conveniently update the excel whenever changes happen, I am ok

Answer (score 0):

You just have to invert the logic:

- close Word
- rename your old sourcefile to Something like "OldBook1, or meve it into a different folder
- rename your new file to "Book1"
- reopen Word

This is also more consistent from an organisational point of view. Best practice (used also in ISO norms) is to move old  files to a subfolder or different folder altogether (maybe renaming the files in the process), and to keep the currently valid files always in the same place woth the same name. It is also the logic used by any automatic backup which needs to keep a history of specific files.

Comment: Sorry, not sure if I follow you, I am going to recreate the reports I need every year/month, are you suggesting I to use the same active directory for the workings and then just make copy whenever I need to make archives?